# Firebase: Failed to parse app error occured during parsing function trigger

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

when i try to deployee function it gives some issues. below is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addNewMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then((snapshot) => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    return res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
  });

});
```

when i am trying to deploye i face issue enter link description here

[image]

i don't understand what is issue exactly . for firebase-admin module **is there need to enable or set Environment Configuration ?** if yes then how ? i dont find this any document i any one no please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in the latest version of firebase-tools, version 3.18.2:

> Fixed issue where some users encountered "Failed to parse app options file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" during functions deployment.

to upgrade:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@3.18.2
```

more info here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.18.2